# SQL Transact-Sql Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get information from multiple tables and tried to do so with an inner join, although it appears that my syntax is correct, I get an error about Transact- Sql statements. I read documentation on case statements, but need clarification as to what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    person.Id, person.firstName, person.lastName, person.birthdate, 
    Gender.Gender, household.Id, family.Id
FROM 
    (((person
INNER JOIN 
    family ON persons.Id = family.Id)
INNER JOIN 
    household ON persons.Id = household.Id)
INNER JOIN 
    Gender ON persons.id = Gender.Id);
```

Error:

> Only SELECT Transact-Sql statements can be used.

Comment: lose the brackets/parentheses

Comment: I'm wondering if your tables match your query. I'm not sure what a separate Gender table with a foreign key for persons gives you that a gender column in persons would not. And I would expect persons to have a foreign key for family, as multiple persons are in one family. Can you show the schema?

Comment: what are u trying to do

Comment: What is your ACTUAL query? Because you say there's an issue with case statements but there is no case statement in your example...

Comment: I'm trying to get the unique Family ID (family table), unique Person ID (person table), gender (I believe this is a separate table because there is gender identification which is data type 'varchar' and gender, which is data type integer with a value of 1 or 2), birthdate (person table), a unique Household ID (household table), first name (person table) and last name (person table).

Comment: there will be genderid in gender table and householdid in houshold tbale jo    SELECT person.Id, person.firstName, person.lastName, person.birthdate, Gender.Gender, household.Id, family.Id

FROM person 
INNER JOIN family ON persons.Id = family.Id
INNER JOIN household ON persons.householdId = household.Id
INNER JOIN Gender ON persons.Genderid = Gender.Id

Comment: The error you've got IS NOT SQL Server error. So maybe it's your GUI error . Can you update your question with the PICTURE of this error?

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove all parentheses for this case:

```
SELECT 
person.Id, person.firstName, person.lastName, person.birthdate, 
Gender.Gender, household.Id, family.Id
FROM  person
INNER JOIN family ON persons.Id = family.Id
INNER JOIN household ON persons.Id = household.Id
INNER JOIN Gender ON persons.id = Gender.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you have in its current state is trying to select from a derived table.

Simply remove the parenthesis to set up your proper joins.

```
    SELECT 
    person.Id, person.firstName, person.lastName, person.birthdate, 
    Gender.Gender, household.Id, family.Id
    FROM  person
    INNER JOIN family ON person.Id = family.Id
    INNER JOIN household ON person.Id = household.Id
    INNER JOIN Gender ON person.id = Gender.Id
```